# Does a hybrid mobile app have permissions to download and open a document

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, windows

I have developed a hybrid mobile app in phonegap. The app is working fine on both android and IOS, but I am facing an issue on Windows.  The issue is that when I open a document in my app with its url, I am not able to get the document. It is just showing loading icon. I'm doubting that it is possible to download and open a document in a hybrid mobile app with document url.  Is that the case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean hosted configuration using via <content src="http://app.host.net" /> you can check out [these docs](https://gist.github.com/daserge/19ddee0c51b29395e841).

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) may be able to help you figure out your issue.  It looks like there are some quirks with the Windows FileReader and FileWriter that aren't present on other devices, so I'm hoping that is the source of your issue.

Alternatively, you might be able to get [this plugin](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) to work as long as you understand where in the file system the downloaded document is.  The documentation here isn't as good, but it seems like you could get the understanding of each devices filesystem that you would need from the other plugin.

Also, [this page from the microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx) has some more information on launching apps and opening files from file and uri associations, which sounds like what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

windows phone does not gives enough permissions to access its internal storage for downloading, saving or retrieving all types of files.
you cannot download `document` but you can for music, videos or podcasts

Comment: How is it possible.?? Documents are the very basic thing in any app. if one cannot download and open even a document in windows phone then no one will use the windows platform.

Comment: platform varies from device to device...on a lumia 510 you can do nothing, but on 520 or higher versions, you can